# How can I set up a download link to a pdf in rails 3.2?

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new with Rails and I'm having trouble understanding why the following error occurs.  I have a page where I've linked a pdf file and some images for download.

In the view:

```
link_to( image_tag('image.png'),:controller=>'home',:action=>'download', :file_name =>  'image.pdf') %>
```

In the controller:

```
def download 
  send_file "#{RAILS_ROOT}/assets/pdf/#{params[:file_name]}", :type=>"text/pdf" 
end
```

When I try to download the file in the development environment I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets"
```

I've tried changing the path to the file and searching on google and SO.  I imagine this must be a relatively simple fix and probably has to do with the asset pipeline but if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there I ran into this issue myself and the solution for me (rails 2.0.2) was to put the pdf file into the public directory of your application and make a direct link www.yoursite.com/my.pdf this will execute the download right away.

Why is this?
well once you deploy your app the rake assets:precompile will be ran and therefor the assets will appear in your public directory.

You can also do this local by running

```
$:. rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV="development"
```

Although I would not advice commiting these files.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution that I ended up using.  I'm still not really sure why I was getting the assets path error.  I suppose that's connected to another issue...

Comment: @dennis What do you mean by public directory of the application ? I have a rails application and now if I want to put a pdf file where should I put this ? 

I want to load this pdf file from CDN that is final goal.

Comment: @SumitKandoi My response is extremely old (10 years!!) but the method still works, if you put a file in your /public folder of your app it will be available from the root of the domain name.

So put test.txt in path/to/app_name/public and access it through app_name.com/test.txt